# Test environment management for a large landscape with 50+ with various architecture type

Tags: software-development, project-management, software-testing, continuous-integration, quality-assurance

I am looking for tool that is capable of centrally managing a complex & large landscape of test applications.

The test environment includes 50+ apps with variety of architecture types & hosted on 5+ different infrastructures -- mainframe, native, Cloud, Tandem, etc. There are 80+ integration points between the apps. Some apps are highly coupled or have strong dependencies.

There are many different test groups involved. To complicate things further, there are many different providers that manage & host a subset of applications independently from each other. There is no standardized delivery methodology - some groups have continuous delivery -- majority rely on manual intervention & processes to upgrade and maintain applications.

There are hard dependencies between applications and test schedules (across different test groups).

The tool should be able to easily and effectively handle the complexity of the environment. It should be easy to track application status (e.g. version). The tool should provide booking & scheduling mechanisms along with providing versatile reporting and visibility capabilities.

Most importantly, the tool should be easy to use and adopt, for both non-technical and technical PMs.

Comment: Personally, I don't know such a tool, that, especially, should be easy to use for everyone. I would recommend custom implementation on top of **container orchestration software** (e.g. Nomad or Kubernetes) in connection with service discovery and provisioning tools (Consul, Ansible or Chef, Terraform). But it is formidable challenge, that require a great deal of technical skill. Since there is no clear answer, let it be comment.